Apk can't find data
in apk I haven't data [picture in apk ] where I installed the application(https://i.sstatic.net/6Hwg3FpB.png).
in emulator I have data picture in emulator  
Why data is showed in emulator but it doesn't showed in apk please?
I tried to solve this pb but it doesn't work
I tried but it doesn't work

Please show the relevant code parts that fail in your app.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
